# ILOG - version 8.0.1

Tags: ilog, jrules, ibm-odm

Sometimes when the rules are deployed from the decision center to RES, although the recent changes are visible in the new archive, on RES, but the execution results don't reflect them.  It is as if the changes are not recognized at execution time. A second deployment without any changes to the rules, will fix the situation.  Can somebody explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can try couple of things -

1. The XU MBean ruleset archive changed/modified notification might be failing. Check if you have the necessary access for this notification. You can try logging into the RES and Diagnostics->Run Diagnostics; and see if there are any errors. Also, you can see the ODM server logs for any errors, when you deploy the ruleset.
2. Check if there is any caching issue